# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing _ input.split

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Today, I wrote this code.

```
a, b = map(int, input("").split(""))
print(a)
```

However, When I enter the number a, b, I keep getting this error

```
File "<string>", line 1

2 3
  ^

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I don't know why I keep getting the error.
Please help

Comment: `a, b = map(int, input("Enter numbers").split(" "))` ?

Comment: Yes. Except the print(a).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use => `input.split(" ").`

If you use `split("")`, which will take the consecutive 2 items like , `"a"` and `" "` as per this case. So, `3` is the extra input you are giving.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I use the code => a, b = map(int, input("").split(" ")).          But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I have tried with online compiler and its working. Can you please check whether there are extra piece of code somewhere in yours

Comment: Don't pass anything in `split()`